# Is there a charging quota for youtube crawler?

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to get the subscriber list of some YouTube accounts, about 100k accounts.
tokens are enough now, and I tried get method like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?key=xxx&channelId=xxx&maxResults=50&part=snippet
```

but the quota limits my crawling speed, how can i get rid of this limitation?

Answer (score 0):

The YouTube api has a very limited quota to begin with. You will need to aplly for a quota extension from the Google developer console under the library tab and search for the YouTube Data api.

You will need to be pasent.  It takes time to get a quota extension.